# I want to check the value of fields of two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have an application, in the app there two forms which are about contact info, each form in different tab; users need to fill. What I want to do  is check if the value of the first form values equal the second form. The below is what I did.

What do you think about this way is efficient? If not or have a better way, please share with me.

```
 // form 1
    var fName = $("#FirstName").val();
    var lName = $("#LastName").val();
    var street = $("#Street").val();
    var city = $("#City").val();
    var cellPhone = $("#cellPhone").val();
    var email = $('#Email').val();


    // form2 of the main contact
    var fName2 = $("#FirstName2").val();
    var lName2 = $("#LastName2").val();
    var street2 = $("#Street2").val();
    var city2 = $("#City2").val();
    var cellPhone2 = $("#cellPhone2").val();
    var email2 = $('#Email2').val();

    //actually i have along "if"
    if(fName==fName2 && lName == lName2 && street==street2 && city==city2 && cellPhone==cellPhone2 && email==email2){

    }
    else {

    }
```

Comment: You want to check all values same or a single value ?

Comment: all values ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var form1 = {
    firstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
    lastName: $("#LastName").val(),
    street: $("#Street").val(),
    city: $("#City").val(),
    cellPhone: $("#cellPhone").val(),
    email: $('#Email').val()
}
var form2 = {
    firstName: $("#FirstName2").val(),
    lastName: $("#LastName2").val(),
    street: $("#Street2").val(),
    city: $("#City2").val(),
    cellPhone: $("#cellPhone2").val(),
    email: $('#Email2').val()
}
for (var k in form1) {
    if (form1[k] === form2[k]) return false
}
// your code
```

Doing so makes it easier for you to add fields.

And I think collecting these data can also be done with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery form validation plugin. Its simple to use and offers lot of validation methods. You can also code your custom methods

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using jquery you can use the $.submit() method. This allows you to run additional functions before the form is submitted. you can simply:

```
$('#someForm1').submit(function (e) {
    var val1 = $(this).find('.inputval1').val();
    var val2 = $('#someForm2').find('.inputval1').val();

    if (val1 === val2) {
        return;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```